# Solved but I'm not sure why: Google Service Account Authentication fails in Ubuntu, works on on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, ubuntu, gspread, oauth2client

I have a python script successfully updating google sheets through Raspberry pi using `oauth2client` and `gspread`.  When I try and run the same script off my desktop Ubuntu it throws an error `403 Insufficient Permissions`. I'm running them both in `IDLE2` if that matters.

I am a novice, but I have imported `gspread` & `oauth2client` libraries, and some things called `pypy`, `openSSL` & `pycrypto`. I have copied the whole folder from the Raspberry pi and am running it out of that folder so it contains the same `json` Key document.

I'm probably missing something obvious.  If you can answer, please dumb it down for a relative newbie.  Thanks.

Update 9:20PM March 13:  I downloaded new credentials from google directly to Ubuntu, updated the code and tried again but received the same error.

Here's the error:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/heather/Desktop/Heather/DEV/18-03-11-Category-Log.py", line 15, in <module>
    wks = gc.open("meditation_logger").sheet1
  File "/home/heather/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/v4/client.py", line 103, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files()
  File "/home/heather/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/v4/client.py", line 80, in list_spreadsheet_files
    r = self.request('get', url)
  File "/home/heather/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/v4/client.py", line 73, in request
    raise APIError(response)
APIError: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}`
```

Here's the code (I've used #### to cover my key file name):

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime
import serial
from time import localtime, strftime
#import time
import serial

#rpi serial port with arduino
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('################.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
#sh = gc.create('meditation_logger1')
wks = gc.open("meditation_logger").sheet1
wks.resize(1)

#wks.update_acell('B2', 'crud')

def ok_to_begin():
    print "ok to begin"

ok_to_begin()

while True:
    wks = gc.open("meditation_logger").sheet1
    data = ser.readline().strip()
```

(... etc. I think the rest of the code isn't really relevant.. just logging instructions for different serial data)

Comment: I got it working!  For some reason I needed to define scope differently when running the script off Ubuntu.  No clue why.  If anyone has ideas please share.  Here is what I did if anyone runs into the same problem:  I changed scope to `scope = [
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]`  as per this page: [gspread API Reference Insufficient Permissions](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=insufficient%20permissions)

Comment: This is because gspread has been upgraded. It now uses API v4. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49295205/318359 for the details.