# gspread python Traceback error

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, gspread

Hello i was looking for this problem 1 - 2 hours and couldnt find anything which is similar to mine.
When i start the py i get a traceback error. I did the same things as in the tutorials.
1. I got the GDrive API and authorize it (Account)
2. i shared my Spreadsheet from google to the e-mail given by the Api
3. installed gspread and oauth2client

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


scope = ["https//spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"]
cred = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("gsecrets.json", scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(cred)
table = gc.open('KeywordKGR').sheet1

def getCellValue(row, col):
    return table.cell(row, col).value

print(getCellValue(1,1))
```

The Error that i receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:./Allintitle/niche.py", line 8, in <module>
    gc = gspread.authorize(cred)
  File "C:.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\__init__.py", line 41, in authorize
    client.login()
  File "C:.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\v4\client.py", line 51, in login
    self.auth.refresh(http)
  File "C:.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 545, in refresh
    self._refresh(http)
  File "C:.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 749, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http)
  File "C:.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 819, in _do_refresh_request
    raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_scope: https//spreadsheets.google.com/feeds is not a valid audience string.
```

Comment: Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Adding a link to your tutorial might help

Comment: german link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otwMWJBSB-A
english link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vISRn5qFrkM

Comment: @KaanDev check this answer to see if it helps in your case https://stackoverflow.com/a/49295205/318359

Comment: thanks @Burnash it helped me alot